# Kotlin app takes a long time to connect to server when not using wifi

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, mobile

I have developed a small simple mobile application with Kotlin for an attendance register that only has a login and an attendance data record. There are 4 connections to the database(that is in Brasil and I'm in Lima, my webpage is very fast so the conection is good): one to check if there is a connection to the database when starting the application, one to log in, one to list the logged data, and one to save the log. The whole app is fully optimized and published on play store, the only problem is that when I use the app with wi-fi it works very fast (about 3 seconds per connection) and everything is fine, but when I connect with mobile data every connection with the database takes approximately 45 seconds.

As an example I leave you with a connection that is the first in the MainActivity, this only verifies that there is a connection with the server. While testing, I noticed that if I remove the line that verifies the connection(val resultado = conexion.comprobarConection()), my app works in almost a second, so I can infer that the only thing that is slowing down my app is the connection with my web server. I've checked my code, compared it to other codes, even asked ChatGPT and everything seems to be optimized and in order. The problem is that if I run the app with Wi-Fi it is super fast and if I run it with mobile data it takes approx. 45sec to load each connection.

I don't know what to do, I have optimized everything I could but I don't see any improvement in response time with mobile data. Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

**MainActivity**

```kotlin
    override fun onStart(){  
        super.onStart()  
        lifecycleScope.launch {  
            if (NetworkUtils.isInternetAvailable(this@MainActivity)) {  
                try {  
                    val resultado = conexion.comprobarConection()  

                    // Realizar acciones basadas en el resultado  
                    if (resultado.isSuccessful) {  
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {  
                            // Actualizar la UI si es necesario  
                            if(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this@MainActivity)?.isLoggedIn == true) {  
                                startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, RegistroActivity::class.java))  
                            } else {  
                                startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, LoginActivity::class.java))  
                            }  
                        }  
                    } else {  
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {  
                            // Mostrar mensajes de error o realizar acciones específicas si la conexión falla  
                            binding.textoSinConeEdu.isVisible = true  
                            binding.btnLlamarSistemas.isVisible = true  
                        }  
                    }  
                } catch (e: Exception) {  
                    // Manejar cualquier excepción que pueda surgir durante la conexión  
                    e.printStackTrace()  
                    // Puedes mostrar un mensaje de error al usuario o realizar acciones específicas  
                }  
            } else {  
                binding.textoSinCone.isVisible = true  
                binding.btnReintentar.isVisible = true  
                binding.btnCerrarApp.isVisible = true  
            }  

        }  
    }
```

Rest of usages:

**NetworkUtils**

```
object NetworkUtils {
fun isInternetAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val network = connectivityManager.activeNetwork
    val capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
    return capabilities != null && (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) || capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR))
}
```

**RetrofitHelper**

```
object RetrofitHelper {

private const val URL = "https://educontable.org/servicios/kotlin/"

fun getInstance(): Retrofit {
    val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE)
    val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()

    val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create()

    return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build()
}
```

}

**ConectionServide**

```
interface ConectionService {

@GET("conexion_kotlin.php")
suspend fun comprobarConection(): Response<ConectionResponse>
```

}

**ConectionResponse**

```
data class ConectionResponse(
@SerializedName("mensaje") val mensaje: String
```

)

**PHP file on my web server for app and server conection**

```
ob_start();
date_default_timezone_set('America/Lima');

require "../../config/conexion.php";

Class Prueba_conexion {
    public function __construct(){
    }
    public function contar_admin(){
        $sql = "SELECT count(*) as cont FROM user_admin";
        return ejecutarConsulta($sql); 
    }

}
$prueba_conexion = new Prueba_conexion();


$rspta = $prueba_conexion->contar_admin();
$reg = $rspta->fetch_object();


if($reg->cont > 0){
    $result = array();
    $result = array(
        "estado"=>"Conectado"
    );
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```